# minimum time to travel between stations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, minimum-spanning-tree

I have implemented a Java program that aims to find the minimum time required to reach each station based on the given bus schedules using Breadth-First Search (BFS). However, the program consistently produces -1 as the output for all stations. I have carefully reviewed the code and I am unable to identify the cause of the issue. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the program is not providing the expected results. Thank you in advance for your help.
The input to the program consists of the following parts:

The first line contains two space-separated integers: N and M. N represents the total number of stations, and M represents the number of buses.

The next M lines describe the schedule of each bus. Each line starts with an integer, t, which represents the number of stations visited by that bus. Following t, there are t integers indicating the sequence of stations visited by the bus.

The output of the program is a single line containing N-1 space-separated integers. Each integer represents the minimum time required to reach a particular station (except the first station) from the starting station. If a station is not reachable based on the given bus schedules, the corresponding output will be -1.

In the provided sample input, we have 8 stations and 4 buses. The schedule of each bus is as follows:

Bus 1: Visits stations 5 and 4.
Bus 2: Visits stations 6, 1, and 2.
Bus 3: Visits stations 4, 2, 1, and 3.
Bus 4: Visits stations 7 and 8.
Based on these schedules, the program calculates the minimum time required to reach each station. The sample output is "2 3 4 6 3 -1 -1", which means it takes 2 minutes to reach station 2, 3 minutes to reach station 3, 4 minutes to reach station 4, 6 minutes to reach station 6, 3 minutes to reach station 7, and stations 8 and beyond are not reachable (-1).

```
`import java.util.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Step 1: Parse the input values
   

    // Step 2: Perform BFS to find the minimum time to reach each station
    int[] minTime = new int[N];
    Arrays.fill(minTime, -1); // Initialize all stations as unreachable
    minTime[0] = 0; // First station is reachable with 0 time

    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    queue.offer(0); // Start BFS from the first station

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        int station = queue.poll();

        for (List<Integer> schedule : buses) {
            int time = minTime[station] + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < schedule.size(); i++) {
                int nextStation = schedule.get(i);

                if (nextStation == station) {
                    // If the bus visits the current station, update the time to reach next station
                    i++; // Skip the current station
                    if (i < schedule.size()) {
                        nextStation = schedule.get(i);
                        if (minTime[nextStation] == -1 || time < minTime[nextStation]) {
                            minTime[nextStation] = time;
                            queue.offer(nextStation);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Step 3: Print the minimum time to reach each station (except the first station)
    
}
}
```

`

what modification can I do to get the expected output

input is
8 4
2 5 4
3 6 1 2
4 4 2 1 3
2 7 8
output of this code is -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
the expected output is 2 3 4 6 3 -1 -1

Comment: Could you please edit your question and start with a description of the challenge, and what the meaning is of the input?

Comment: There are N bus stations and M buses in Ankara Kızılay. Each bus has a schedule with t stations. You start at station 1 and can board a bus when you and the bus are at the same station. You want to find the minimum time to reach each station, or determine if it's impossible. Output the times for stations 2 to N in numerical order. If a station is unreachable, output -1. You can only travel by bus.

Comment: Can you explain what each of the numbers are in the input? Since this question is about *timing*... where can we find or deduce what the time is a bus will be at a certain station? Do all buses start driving at the same time? Does the trip of one station to the next always take the same time?

Comment: Find the minimum time required to reach each station from the starting station, or determine if it is impossible. You can only travel by bus and use multiple buses if needed. Buses operate on schedules provided as input, where each schedule lists the stations the bus visits in order.

Comment: Sample Input:
8 4
2 5 4
3 6 1 2
4 4 2 1 3
2 7 8

Sample Output:
2 3 4 6 3 -1 -1

Comment: But what is the *meaning* of the input schedule. What does 8 mean here? What does 4 mean? ...etc. Where are the station numbers and where are the times?

Comment: Given 8 stations and 4 buses, each bus follows a schedule of stations it visits in a specific order. For example, the second bus visits stations 6, 1, and 2. Travel between each station takes 1 minute, resulting in a 2-minute travel time from the 6th station to the 2nd station for the second bus.
Sample Input:
8 4\n
2 5 4\n
3 6 1 2\n
4 4 2 1 3n\
2 7 8\n

Sample Output:
2 3 4 6 3 -1 -1
(\n: go back to new line)

Comment: All buses start at the same time? Should we assume that when the first bus is at station 5, the last bus is at station 7? Can you edit your question and make sure the input/output is formatted (surround by lines with three backticks)?

Comment: yes they start at the same time

Comment: for better understanding take a look a this pdf it has the question 2
https://lms.tedu.edu.tr/pluginfile.php/180667/mod_resource/content/2/Homework%203.pdf

Comment: That website is protected. I don't have access. Please edit your question to add the additional information, and reformat the input/output.

Comment: I tried to but I couldn't write the whole idea in here so Ill really appreciate if you take a look in this document, it explain the problem and the input/output in question 2 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f0IqoDOBJKJFbMsz8wvFn3DJjm4_1fr5kqEU7A7vgNM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, but you should make sure all necessary information is in the question, not behind the link.

Comment: This code solves the problem of finding the minimum time needed to reach each station using a combination of BFS (Breadth-First Search) and graph traversal. 

In the given sample input, there are 8 stations and 4 buses. Each bus has a schedule of stations it visits, and the number of stations visited by each bus is provided. The sample output is a sequence of numbers representing the minimum time needed to reach each station (except the first station) in numerical order.

Comment: The code reads the input values, initializes the minimum time array, and starts BFS from the first station. It iterates over the buses and checks if a bus visits the current station. If it does, it updates the time to reach the next station and adds it to the queue for further exploration. This process continues until all reachable stations are visited.

Finally, the code prints the minimum time to reach each station (except the first station) based on the calculated values. In the given sample output, the minimum times are 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, -1, -1 for stations 2 to 8, respectively.

Comment: Sample Input:

(new line)8 4

(new line)2 5 4

(new line)3 6 1 2

(new line)4 4 2 1 3

(new line)2 7 8

Sample Output:
(new line)2 3 4 6 3 -1 -1

Comment: I give up. Apparently I am not clear in my comments. Have a nice day.

Comment: The input to the program consists of the following parts:

The first line contains two space-separated integers: N and M. N represents the total number of stations, and M represents the number of buses.

The next M lines describe the schedule of each bus. Each line starts with an integer, t, which represents the number of stations visited by that bus. Following t, there are t integers indicating the sequence of stations visited by the bus.

Comment: The output of the program is a single line containing N-1 space-separated integers. Each integer represents the minimum time required to reach a particular station (except the first station) from the starting station. If a station is not reachable based on the given bus schedules, the corresponding output will be -1.

Comment: I just did edit it

Answer (score -1):

I also tried djiskrat algorithm but same problem

```
  import java.util.*;

  public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Step 1: Read the input values
     

        // Step 2: Initialize the minTime array
        int[] minTime = new int[N];
        Arrays.fill(minTime, -1);
        minTime[0] = 0;

        // Step 3: Use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the minimum time
        PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();
        pq.offer(new Node(0, 0));

        while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
            Node node = pq.poll();
            int station = node.station;
            int time = node.time;

            if (time > minTime[station]) {
                continue; // Skip if we have found a shorter time to reach this 
                                       station
            }

            for (List<Integer> schedule : buses) {
                for (int i = 0; i < schedule.size(); i++) {
                    if (schedule.get(i) == station) {
                        int travelTime = 1; // Time taken to travel to the next 
                                        station

                        int nextIndex = (i + 1) % schedule.size();
                        int nextStation = schedule.get(nextIndex);

                        int nextTime = time + travelTime;
                        if (minTime[nextStation] == -1 || nextTime < 
                           minTime[nextStation]) {
                            minTime[nextStation] = nextTime;
                            pq.offer(new Node(nextStation, nextTime));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Step 4: Print the minimum time to reach each station
        
    }

    static class Node implements Comparable<Node> {
        int station;
        int time;

        public Node(int station, int time) {
            this.station = station;
            this.time = time;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Node other) {
            return Integer.compare(time, other.time);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post this as an answer, but edit your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).